# Can't get any data on Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I collected a lot of tweet. Then I want to output only English tweets. I can get all of tweet included non-English tweet. But if I append some code `for i in range (0,1000): if tweet['statuses'][i][u'lang']==u'en':` for getting only English tweet, it can't be collected like that. And there are no error.

```
In [1]: runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/tweets.py', wdir='C:/Users/Desktop')
```

It just runs and there(`"C:/Users/Desktop/A.txt"`) are no data. My code is as follows. What should I do with it?

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

tweets_filename = 'C:/Users/Desktop/tweet.txt' #Original tweet
tweets_file = open(tweets_filename, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line.strip())
        for i in range (0,1000): #This is the part for filtering English tweet
            if tweet['statuses'][i][u'lang']==u'en': #Same part
                if 'text' in tweet: 
                    print (tweet['created_at']) 
                    print (tweet['text']) 
                    hashtags = []
                    for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
                        hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])
                        print(hashtags)

                    output = "C:/Users/Desktop/A.txt" #Only English tweet path
                    out_file = open(output, 'a')
                    out_file.write(tweet['user']['name'] + "," + tweet['text'] + "\n \n")
                    out_file.close()

except:
    continue
```

Comment: There are no errors becase you explicitly catch and silence them. **Don't do that**.

Comment: What Daniel said. You shouldn't use "bare" except. _Always_ use named exceptions, otherwise you might catch something that you weren't expecting. A "bare" except is the Python equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and shouting "La la la, I can't hear you" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the lines of `tweet_file`, like this;

```
lines = tweet_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    ...
```

Also, if you want to see the errors. Donät catch them. Some good reading [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)